# How to show tooltip only when data available in chart js?

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, chart.js

How to show tooltip only when data available in chart js?

[image]

```
callbacks: {
  title: (item, data) => this.projectNumberArray[item[0].index],
  label: (item, data) => this.projectNameArray[item.index]
},
```

And I want disable tooltip, when I don't have needed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been faced same problem several days ago. I checked documentation and github both but i couldn't find the solution for disabling tooltip when data is not available.

Then i found a solution.

Then i checkced data on runtime and set a variable. When i draw chart then i check variable which i have been set on runtime and disable the tooltip accordingly.

```
tooltips: {
      enabled: false
```

}

You can use above piece of code for disabling tooltip while drawing chart on canvas.